# Organize import for generated code

Tags: java, import, eclipse-plugin

I have written an Eclipse plug-in to generate Java code using xpand2. The beautifier support available with it does not organize imports.

So, I intend to use the organize imports option available in Eclipse. Can someone help me understand as to how I can plug-in that option to my Eclipse plug-in?